# Examples of surface automorphisms with no periodic points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, automorphism-groups

Consider a smooth projective complex surface $S$ with an automorphism $g:S\to S$. A point $p$ is *periodic* if it has finite orbit under iterates of $g$.

> What are some examples of surface automorphisms $g$ with no periodic points?

For example, $S$ can be an abelian variety and $g$ could be translation by some general point $\tau\in S$. Are there others, say on a rational surface, or a K3 surface?

Comment: Every automorphism of a projective rationally connected variety over any field has a fixed point (you can prove this by reduction to the case of finite fields, where the automorphism is automatically finite order).  So you cannot find examples on projective rational surfaces.

Comment: By the "Wood's Hole", Atiyah-Bott, holomorphic Lefschetz fixed point formula, an automorphism $g$ of a (projective, complex) K3 surface has a fixed point so long as $g^*$ does not act on $H^0(S,\omega_S)$ as $-1$.  However, even if $g^*$ does act as $-1$, then for $h=g\circ g$, then $h^*$ acts as $+1$, and thus $h=g\circ g$ has fixed points.  So there will also be no examples on projective, complex K3 surfaces.

Comment: Just to point out one more thing: if your automorphism $g$ fixes an ample invertible sheaf, then the action of $g$ on the complete linear system of any tensor power of the invertible sheaf admits a fixed point.  Thus, there is a fixed curve inside your surface.  Dynamics on curves are easy to understand, and essentially your curve must be arithmetic genus $1$ if it has no periodic orbits.  In particular, that rules out Kobayashi hyperbolic surfaces.

Comment: @JasonStarr: Kobayashi hyperbolic surfaces are of general type, so the automorphism group is finite.

Comment: Another elementary example is the product of an elliptic curve with any other curve. I would guess that the only other examples are fixed point free quotient of ones as above (as well as general abelian surfaces).

Answer (score 5):

This is just the collection of my comments above.  First of all, for every automorphism $g$ (finite order or not) of every proper, smooth, separably rationally connected variety $X$ over any field $k$, the fixed scheme $X^g$ is nonempty.  So there will be no examples with $X$ a rational surface.

Second, by the holomorphic Lefschetz fixed point theorem, if $h^{1,0}(X) = 0$ or $1$ and if $h^{2,0}(X)$ equals $1$, then $g$ or $g\circ g$ has a fixed point.  If $h^{1,0}(X)$ equals $0$ and $h^{2,0}(X)$ equals $0$, then $g$ has a fixed point.

Finally, if $g$ preserves an effective divisor class, then $g$ preserves an effective divisor in that class.  Thus the effective divisor is genus $1$.  This rules out Kobayashi hyperbolic examples.

Answer (score 0):

Many examples are given in [Friedman-Morgan, Page 22.](https://books.google.com/books?id=38Z9D2DB2KMC&pg=PA22&lpg=PA22&dq=complex%20surface%20automorphisms%20without%20fixed%20points&source=bl&ots=gDnxpc9nz0&sig=tb2tjWiqnWosZqvEyJuj_WvqDaw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=f5MtVc3wPObksATP5IGoDg&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=complex%20surface%20automorphisms%20without%20fixed%20points&f=false)

**EDIT** The infinite order situation is discussed in t[he paper by Oguiso (2012).](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.2637.pdf)

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how these examples are relevant - $g$ should have infinite order here.

Comment: I think the automorphisms in Oguiso's paper are fixed point free but not aperiodic.

Comment: I do not see how the paper of Oguiso addresses the question.  Even if $g$ has no fixed point, nonetheless, $g\circ g$ must have a fixed point by the holomorphic Lefschetz fixed point theorem.  So even if Oguiso calls this automorphism "free", that does not mean it has no periodic orbits.

Comment: @J.C.Ottem: We both made the same comment (nearly) simultaneously.